# How to add elements of python lists in a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays

Below is list of arrays:

```
{'array_1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'array_2': [3, 4, 5, 6], 'array_3': [7, 8, 9, 0]}
```

Code for array input:

```
def main():

  a = int(input("Enter the number of array's: "))
  size = int(input('Each array size: '))
  arrays = dict()
  for i in range(1, a + 1):

    arrays['array_' + str(i)] = list(
    map(lambda j: int(input('value: ')), [j for j in range(size)]))

  print(arrays)
```

I want to add 'array_1' with array_2

Comment: What do you mean by add? `[1,2,3]` and `[10,20,30]` will become `[11,22,33]` or `[1,2,3,10,20,30]` ?

Comment: That's not a list of arrays. It's a `dict` of `list`s.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification, you have a dictionary of lists, not a list of arrays. I think this is what you're looking for

```
list_dict = {'array_1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'array_2': [3, 4, 5, 6], 'array_3': [7, 8, 9, 0]}
[sum(items) for items in zip(list_dict['array_1'], list_dict['array_2'])]
```

this results in the list `[4, 6, 8, 10]` - I'm assuming that's what you mean by add array_1 and array_2

Answer (score 1):

If by `add` you mean `concatenate` do this:

```
new_list = array['array_1'] + array['array_2']
```

else if you mean addition of individual values you can do:

```
from operator import add
new_array = list(map(add,array['array_1'],array['array_2']))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum element wise then

```
d= {'array_1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'array_2': [3, 4, 5, 6], 'array_3': [7, 8, 9, 0]}

[sum(x) for x in zip(*d.values())] # will add elements from all the lists
```

Output:

```
[11, 14, 17, 10]
```

going along the same lines if you just want to add lists corresponding to some keys then you can filter the keys to create a new dict and use it in a same way

```
[sum(x) for x in zip(*{key:value for key,value in d.items() if key in ['array_1','array_2']}.values())]
```

Output

```
[4, 6, 8, 10]
```